# Call Angular service inside forEach loop

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am beginner in Angular 4.
I want to calculate total invoice in EUR curency,
I have value of prices and currenciy type for each price. When I want to calculate total sum, I need to call exchangeService service , in order to get exchange rate of currency.

When I inspect the value of invoicesSumTotalValue it is 0.
Here is my code:

```js
    calcInvTotalValue(){

     let prods = (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.productData.parent.parent).parent).controls['products']);
        let invoicesSumTotalValue = 0;


        prods.controls.forEach(c => {
          let price = (<FormGroup>(<FormGroup>c).controls['selected_products']).controls['price'].value;
          let currency = (<FormGroup>(<FormGroup>c).controls['selected_products']).controls['currency'].value;

          this.exchangeService.getExchRate(currency, "USD").subscribe(
            vl => {
              let exRate = vl;
              invoicesSumTotalValue = invoicesSumTotalValue + (parseFloat(price) * exRate);
            },
            (error: any) => console.log(error)
          );
        });
        console.log("iNVOICE total is: " + invoicesSumTotalValue);
```

How can I call service for each value of prods array ?
Thank you!

Comment: What coding languages are you familiar with? There are several things here I would do differently, but don’t want to write it in a way that might be tough to understand.

Comment: Also, is the service fetching the exchange rate from a server? Or does it already have it?

Comment: @theMayer, I am using Typescript, ANGULAR 2

Comment: I get exchenge rate from an exteranl web service API

Comment: I think he meant, what _other_ languages are you familiar with in order to better tailor the answer to your background

Comment: @paulpdaniels , typescript

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of RxJS's [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to wait for the `Array.forEach()` loop to be completed before returning all the observables. If you are familiar with the usage of Promises in JavaScript, it is actually similar to [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

You will face issues calculating `invoicesSumTotalValue` because the returning of observables is an asynchronous operation, hence it is likely the next iteration of the `forEach` loop will be executed before the response from getExchRate() is returned.

Here is my suggested modifications to your code. Basically, we make use of `forkJoin()` to return the observables once all iterations of the `forEach()` loop have been completed. From there, within the `subscribe()` block where we return the observables, we handle the calculation of `invoicesSumTotalValue`.

```
const prods = (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.productData.parent.parent).parent).controls['products']);
const observablesList = [];

prods.controls.forEach(c => {
  const currency = (<FormGroup>(<FormGroup>c).controls['selected_products']).controls['currency'].value;
   observablesList.push(this.exchangeService.getExchRate(currency, 'USD'));
})

forkJoin(observablesList).subscribe(response => {
  //console.log(response);
  // handle the rest
});
```

Comment: How can implement my logic inside subscribe of forkJoin ??

Comment: @zardosht it is actually very similar to what you already have. Just to clarify your logic, are you trying to add all `price`, multiplied by the `exRate`?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to console.log an asynchronous value "invoicesSumTotalValue" synchronously that's the issue here.

Move the method level variable invoicesSumTotalValue to class level and print the value in HTML template you will get the actual total value.

Since the http service returns an observable of price values it won't be immediately available where you are doing the console.log.

Modify the code  like below and it will work fine : ( I mocked the prod array for my convenience to show the result here )

**Component Code :**

export class ExchangeComponent implements OnInit {

```
invoicesSumTotalValue = 0;

constructor(private exchangeService: ExchangeService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.calcInvTotalValue();
}

calcInvTotalValue() {

    let prods = [
        {
            price: 10,
            currency: 'INR'
        },
        {
            price: 20,
            currency: 'EUR'
        }
    ];

    prods.forEach(c => {
        let price = c['price'];
        let currency = c['currency'];

        this.exchangeService.getExchangeRate("USD", currency).subscribe(
            vl => {
                let exRate = vl['rates'][currency];
                this.invoicesSumTotalValue = this.invoicesSumTotalValue + (parseFloat(String(price)) * parseFloat(exRate));
            },
            (error: any) => console.log(error)
        );
    });
}
```

}

**Template Code :**

{{ invoicesSumTotalValue }}